# How do i program Back button to my Desktop Application Page

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, desktop-application

I am working on a desktop application and i want to add functionality to back button that would take me to my MainControl.xaml Page.

There are a few online codes i have tried but no use. I am relatively a very new coder in C# WPF

I have added the button successfully as follows:

```
`<Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="19,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" Click="Button_Click"/>`
```

The .cs code is this but i dont know what to add

`private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Go to MainControl.xaml
}`
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lc3k.jpg)

Comment: I'm assuming your application is an XBAP app  (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview) ?

Comment: i have added an image of the page i have added the button on, i just wanna know what to write to create a function of back button.

Comment: a) using margins for element positioning is not how you are supposed to use XAML
b) to help you we need to see more of your XAML for example the control you use to display pages

Comment: Please post your complete code - what you've provided so far is insufficient

Comment: @DenisSchaf xaml is working fine, i just need to know a generic code to apply at the back button.

Comment: @auburg the thing is i cannot post the whole xaml, imagine if you had 2 pages and you have to link them via a back button how would you do that in a simple C# code?

Comment: What type of application is this - traditional WPF desktop application or XBAP ? If the former than what do you mean by 'pages' - such a concept doesn't exist in a standard WPF app. Do you mean dialog user controls ?

Comment: @auburg it is a normal desktop application developed in WPF that scans the document. page means a proper page in Visual studio, i am referring to navigation between pages. I want to add a back button.

Comment: Please see this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: If you do not provide more information do not expect help

Answer (score 1):

You've not explained this properly but i guess you have a frame or navigationwindow and I that hosts your pages.

You need a reference to the frame or navigationwindow that hosts your page.

That has a navigationservice.

Which has a goback method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-navigate-back-through-navigation-history

Incidentally.

This sort of navigation is a rare requirement in business business systems I have seen.